# How do I convert a binary pgdump (compressed) to a plain SQL file?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I do want to search for some data inside a database dump but these dumps are using the binary-compressed format (`PGDMP` header).

How can I convert these to SQL without restoring them?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

`pg_restore`, when run without a database name, outputs a text dump to stdout; you can send that elsewhere with `-f` or with I/O redirection.

```
pg_restore -f mydatabase.sql mydatabase.dump
```

Note that you must ensure there's no `PGDATABASE` environment variable set, or it'll try to connect to that database.

Comment: When I try to do this, I get `pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive`. I can assure you that the dumps were made using the same version of postgresql 8.4.17.

Comment: Sorry, I just discovered that the guy that made the backups, gzipped them after using -Fc ?! ... and mc view was showing me the uncompressed content on file-view...

Comment: This was very helpful!

Comment: @sorin Do you solved the issue? I have the same issue now.

Comment: @kripindas They posted in 2014, wouldn't bet on them remembering or seeing this. Post a new question. But first use `file the-archive-file-name` to find out what kind of file it is.

Comment: This worked for me. My file was a .dump file

Answer (score 25):

The fastest method that I've used was:

```
pg_restore -f mybinaryfile.backup > mysqlfile.sql
```

No special flags, since pg_restore just spits it out to stdout.

Comment: I had to add `-f` like this: `pg_restore -f mybinaryfile.backup > mysqlfile.sql`

Comment: I had to add `-f`, and i only wanted to restore one table, so i ended up with this: `pg_restore -f - --table=users my-backup.dump > users.sql`

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you run multiple clusters, the restore command may not like the default version...

> pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.12) in file header

In that case you have to specify the version, host and port as in:

```
pg_restore --cluster 9.1/localhost:5433 -f db.sql db.pgsql
```

(note that the `host:port` info is ignored with the -f option.)

The port (5433) can be determined using the `pgsql` command as in:

```
pgsql --port 5433 template1
```

When `pgsql` connects, it writes a comment such as:

> psql (9.3.6, server 9.1.13)

This means you are running pgsql 9.3.6 and that port 5433 references server 9.1.13.

If you are not sure which ports are currently used, you may use the `netstat` command as in:

```
sudo netstat -a64np | grep LISTEN | grep postgres
```

The `sudo` is required for the `-p` option which prints the process name. That gives you a list of ports (usually TCP and UDP ports).

Finally, on a Debian/Ubuntu system, you can get a list of installed clusters with the `dpkg -l` command as in:

```
dpkg -l '*postgres*'
```

The list of entries that start with 'ii' (left most column) are currently installed. You, of course, have similar commands for other Unices to help you determine installed versions.